# Modify column type in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a column called 'color' which has two kinds of values ('Color' and 'Black and White').

I would like to change the value 'Color' to number 1 and the value 'Black and white' to number 0.

To change it, I'm using this line:

> movies.color = movies.color.map({'Color': 1, ' Black and White':0})

but how do I change the column type, from str to integer? How to make sure that the column is now an integer type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all rows can be mapped the resulting column should be int by default.

You can always do a explicit conversion by doing:

```
movies.color = movies.color.map({'Color': 1, ' Black and White':0}).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thnks @Allen . just another simple question: do u know if it is a good practice to do this explicit conversion?

Comment: I think it's ok in this case as it will ensure the data type is what you expect and if there's non-integers in the column it will give you an error message.